# Consul Lock Keeps Timing Out

Tags: locking, consul

Checking the [Consul Lock documentation](https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/lock.html)

It states that we can specify the timeout using the -try option. I am running the full command as follows:

```
$ consul lock -n 1 -try 2h -monitor-retry 60 -name 'jenkins locking test.tfstate' -verbose ./test.tfstate ./terraform_apply.sh
Setting up lock at path: test.tfstate/.lock
Attempting lock acquisition
```

However, no matter what I set for -try option, `consul lock` always timesout after 20 minutes with the following:

```
Shutdown triggered or timeout during lock acquisition
```

Any ideas how to increase the timeout beyond 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a network connectivity problem in that the server is thinking the heartbeats between the `consul lock` process that starts your `./terraform_apply.sh` and the Consul servers is somehow obstructed.  Additional output from the Consul servers is necessary to provide further help.